# Running a shell command from php

Tags: php, shell

The command below is a shell command that works for me.

`php -f /home3/kintest2/www/project/keygen_msql_adjuster.php`

What i would like to do is the make this command run from a php file.

Any hints are welcomed

Comment: Here're two hints: [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), [`shell_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Comment: [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [backticks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) or [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) or [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php), depending on what you want to do with the process you start.

Comment: I'm trying to execute php from another php file. What the file does is it updates only one database record that satisfies some conditions. But I want the file to continuously execute this file in a loop

Comment: Are think of some kind of a scheduled job, that would kick in in every few minutes/hours? If you are, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

```
include('/home3/kintest2/www/project/keygen_msql_adjuster.php');
```

or is there a particular reason you want to fire off a whole new PHP interpreter instance?

I'd note that a good reason *not* to use `include` is because anything declared therein will pollute your current instance's namespace.

On the flip side, calling `shell_exec` or similar can be a *massive* security hole.  If your code is running in a restricted environment that may not matter, though.

Comment: I'm trying to execute php from another php file. What the file does is it updates only one database record that satisfies some conditions. But I want the file to continuously execute this file in a loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

```
echo shell_exec ( "php -f /home3/kintest2/www/project/keygen_msql_adjuster.php" );
```

Comment: This code works well for any other command. When I use the shell command above it doesn't do anything the page just seems to load for every... Any ideas on why ?

Comment: @CongoleseMedia Could potentially be a permissions problem on that file or folder, or it could be an environment problem, like having safe_mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using a command-running library that handles errors and things properly: 
https://github.com/kamermans/command

Then you can run the program like this:

```
use kamermans\Command\Command;
$cmd = Command::factory('php')
    ->option('-f', 'keygen_msql_adjuster.php')
    ->setDirectory('/home3/kintest2/www/project')
    ->run();
```

Or, more simply put:

```
use kamermans\Command\Command;
$cmd = Command::factory('php -f /home3/kintest2/www/project/keygen_msql_adjuster.php');
```

Unlike PHPs built-in methods, this method will throw a PHP Exception if the command fails, which you can then catch and handle if need be:

```
use kamermans\Command\Command;
use kamermans\Command\CommandException;

$cmd = Command::factory('php')
    ->option('-f', 'keygen_msql_adjuster.php')
    ->setDirectory('/home3/kintest2/www/project');

try {
    $cmd->run();
} catch (CommandException $e) {
    die("The command failed: ".$e->getMessage()."\n");
}
```